# "WARNING: Found @$ in the file __ Possible error suppression is being used

Tags: php, theme-development

In my theme custom admin page, i have some checkboxes. To check whether it is checked or not i am using following method.

```
function mega_menu_deactivater() {
    $mega_menu_condition = get_option( 'deactivate_mega_menu' );
    $checked = ( @$mega_menu_condition == 1 ? 'checked' : '' );
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="deactivate_mega_menu" name="deactivate_mega_menu" value="1" '.$checked.'>';
}
```

This works fine. But when i run themecheck i get this Warning.

"WARNING: Found @$ in the file functions-admin.php. Possible error suppression is being used."

is there any alternative to overcome this warning.

Comment: Remove the `@`...

Comment: First time i used this function without @. And it gave me an error. But now when i remove @ it works perfectly fine. Any idea about this surprise?

Comment: `@` just suppresses errors. It doesn’t fix anything. There’s no reason that variable would throw an error anyway, so it would’ve had something to do with how your original code was different.